# RobotFramework: Looking for xpath with spaces in search item

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I am not sure how to format strings that im looking for that contain spaces. When i look for a string in format **21 Jun 2017**

```
${date_to_search_for}=    Convert Date    ${completion_date}    date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f     result_format=%d %b %Y    exclude_millis=True
Wait Until Element Is visible  xpath=//*[contains(text(),\"${date_to_search_for}\")]
```

It gives error

```
Element 'xpath=//*[contains(text(),"21 Jun 2017")]' was not visible in 30 seconds
Arguments: [ 'xpath=//*[contains(text(),"21 Jun 2017")]' ]
```

Ive tried escaping the quotes as above and it gives "
When i dont escape them, it gives \"

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using a single quote: `xpath=//*[contains(text(),'${date_to_search_for}')]`

Answer (score 0):

no need to trim spaces when searching xPath. Please check original html element, does it include any other elements (not only text you are searching for)? if yes - change locator to

```
//*[contains(. ,'21 Jun 2017')]
```